# How to keep a function running in background.js even when popup.html is out of view

Tags: javascript

how to keep this timer running even when popup.html is closed?

i am saving the last time in storage so that it resumes from last stopped point
but how to keep the setinterval keep running
manifest has
persistence as true. and this script in background

```js
function timer(){
  if(localStorage.getItem('tile')==null){
    secs=32400;
    }
    
    if(localStorage.getItem('tile')!=null){
      secs=localStorage.getItem('tile');
    }
    console.log(secs);
    if(secs!==0){
     
    function z(n) { return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n; }
    var sign = secs < 0 ? '-' : '';
    secs = Math.abs(secs);
    secs = secs-1;
    


chrome.storage.local.get(["actualtime"],function (result){aht = (((Number(result.actualtime))*((13/8)*60))/(28800-secs)/60);
document.getElementById("time2").innerHTML = aht.toFixed(2);
    })
    aht2 = (((secs/60))*((13/8)))/(28800/60);
    document.getElementById("time3").innerHTML = aht2.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML= sign + z(secs / 3600 | 0) + ':' + z((secs % 3600) / 60 | 0) + ':' + z(secs % 60);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('actualtime'));
   
    localStorage.setItem('tile',secs);
}

}

setInterval(timer,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

cant use the same js for  background as well as for popup.html //mistake i made.
ran a seperate js for background and a js  for popup.html
used msg parsing to communicate between them
Background one kept running and the js for popup.html gets called only when popup.html is opened.(and stops when closed)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).